# request wsdl service array object

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object, wsdl

I am using visual basic .net. I want to operate on wsdl service. I'm having a problem with something. I need to insert data into the service. I have no problem connecting to the service. but I could not run the function by using the objects defined in the wsdl file. I'm waiting for your help.

wsdl file

```html
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:rfc="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" xmlns:p1="http://xxxxxxx.com/Retail/MAYA/TDMStokHareket" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="SI_TDMStokHareket_OB" targetNamespace="http://xxxxxx">
<wsdl:documentation/>
<wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="false"/>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_SI_TDMStokHareket_OB"/>
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
<xsd:element name="ZRT_TDM_STOK_HAREKET">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="ET_RETURN" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" type="ZRS_TDM_STOK_HAREKET_RES" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="IT_DATA" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" type="ZRS_TDM_STOK_HAREKET" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ZRT_TDM_STOK_HAREKET.Response">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="EV_STATU" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ET_RETURN" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" type="ZRS_TDM_STOK_HAREKET_RES" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="IT_DATA" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" type="ZRS_TDM_STOK_HAREKET" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="ZRS_TDM_STOK_HAREKET_RES">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="MESSAGE" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Message Text</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="220"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ZRS_TDM_STOK_HAREKET">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="TDM_KODU" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Search Term 1</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="DSN_KODU" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Search Term 1</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="DSN_ALT_BAYI" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Search Term 1</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="DSN_ALT_BAYI_ADI" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Name</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="MATNR" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Material Number</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="18"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="SERGE" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Manufacturer serial number</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="MENGE" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Quantity</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
<xsd:totalDigits value="13"/>
<xsd:fractionDigits value="3"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="rfc.ZRT_TDM_STOK_HAREKET.Input">
<wsdl:documentation/>
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="rfc:ZRT_TDM_STOK_HAREKET"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="rfc.ZRT_TDM_STOK_HAREKET.Output">
<wsdl:documentation/>
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="rfc:ZRT_TDM_STOK_HAREKET.Response"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="SI_TDMStokHareket_OB">
<wsdl:documentation/>
<wsdl:operation name="SI_TDMStokHareket_OB">
<wsdl:documentation/>
<wsp:Policy>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_SI_TDMStokHareket_OB"/>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:input message="p1:rfc.ZRT_TDM_STOK_HAREKET.Input"/>
<wsdl:output message="p1:rfc.ZRT_TDM_STOK_HAREKET.Output"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

vb code

```
  client.SI_TDMStokHareket_OB(response.ET_RETURN, request.IT_DATA)

    MsgBox(response.ET_RETURN(0).MESSAGE)
```

I can't send data to the function. Can you help with objects and arrays? thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question explain exactly what "I can't send data to the function" means?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem of sending the values to the function as follows

```
 ReDim request.IT_DATA(0)
    request.IT_DATA(0) = New ZRS_TDM_STOK_HAREKET

    request.IT_DATA(0).TDM_KODU = "70031.42002"
    request.IT_DATA(0).DSN_KODU = "70031.42002"
    request.IT_DATA(0).DSN_ALT_BAYI = "00000.12345"
    request.IT_DATA(0).DSN_ALT_BAYI_ADI = "CAGLAR DSN ALT BAYISI"
    request.IT_DATA(0).MATNR = "100000000000001287"
    request.IT_DATA(0).SERGE = "445313311000213"
    request.IT_DATA(0).MENGESpecified = True
    request.IT_DATA(0).MENGE = 1

    client.SI_TDMStokHareket_OB(response.ET_RETURN, request.IT_DATA)

    MsgBox(response.ET_RETURN(0).MESSAGE)
```